# Symfony 1.4: Storing an array in session with SetAttribute

Tags: session, symfony1, attributes, symfony-1.4

I'm wondering if someone knows how to store an array into a user session?

This is the method to store a single attribute:

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('something', $something);
```

And the documentation says:

*"User attributes can store any type of data (strings, arrays, and associative arrays)"*

... but doesn't say anything more. The API documentation doesn't have a "SetAttributes" or something similarly obvious.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uh, as I'd written the question out, it became obvious:

```
$something = array();

$this->getUser()->setAttribute('something', $something);
```

Resolved.

Comment: As an aside, these 'attribute' methods on the 'user' are neatly wrapped beneath the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface, albeit without an ability to specify the `$ns` aka namespace parameter. Soo, one could also write your solution as `$this->getUser()['something'] = $something;`.