# Alternative to write/set/change Values into User Session in Symfony 1.4 when using AJAX to Call Controllers?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I started this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825664/how-to-use-symfony-get-setattribute-on-nested-session-attributes/11826516#11826516) to know how i can get/set Values from the User Session(Symfony 1.4). The Get works perfectly but the Set never works. I can see in the Debug Modus that the Global Session($_SESSION) is updated but the User Session dont. I tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656570/symfony-1-4-storing-an-array-in-session-with-setattribute?rq=1) and [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482002/session-deletion-in-symfony-1-4) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493636/storing-session-data) and at least [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210147/symfony-1-4-how-to-manipulate-the-attributeholder)... Without Success. I never read about such a Bug from Symfony 1.4. I use as Browser(linux) Firefox and Chrome (I tested it into anonymus Tab too).

**Debug Modus User looks like :**

```
attributeHolder:
myNS: { 
     aValue: '15', 
     ns_15: { 
         Tel: '78568951', 
         myID: '15', 
         anotherID: '120', 
         anArray: [{ 
             arrayID: '78', 
             Company: 'myComp'
         }] }, 
     ns_17: { ... } 
}
```

I can change the **aValue** attribute, delete and reinsert it. But the **ns_15** or **ns_17** can be delete or change but this Change cant be affect (symfony Debug Mode) **User**, but just into **$_SESSION** (symfony Debug Modus **Globals** ) i can see the updated values.

Is there another way to set/change/delete or write a value into an User Session with symfony 1.4 or it's a Symfony Bug?

**EDIT1**

I just dont figure it out til i see this [Bug](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/1257) and this [Blog](http://garethmccumskey.blogspot.de/2009/10/php-session-write-locking-and-how-to.html) !! well i'm using AJAX to call the Controller. So that's maybe the reason why i cant write on Session. Another Way i can't really subclass sfWebResponse cause my actions already subclass sfActions. :(

**EDIT2**

Because **Edit1** I tried to make this:

```
  $sessionData = $this->getUser()->getAttribute("ns_15", array(), "myNS");//all good
  $sessionData["Tel"] = "0111111110";
  var_dump($sessionData["Tel"]);//show me 0111111110
  $this->getUser()->setAttribute("ns_15", $sessionData, "myNS");
  $this->getUser()->shutdown();
  sfContext::getInstance()->getStorage()->shutdown();
```

The Behavior with reloading twice is solved,but still cant write into $_SESSION and USER SESSION. ([Same Trouble too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699284/send-two-ajax-request-at-the-same-time-in-symfony)).

Answer (score 0):

I try to summary how you can manipulate the user attributes (note that this not the same as modifying the `$_SESSION` global see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898511/symfony-1-4-session-vs-session-issues) to know why).

```
// set a singe value in a namespace
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('aValue', 15, 'myNS');
// set an array in a namespace
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('ns_15', array('Tel' => '78568951', 'myID' => '15', 'anotherID' => '120', 'anArray' => array(array('arrayID' => '78', 'Company' => 'myComp'))), 'myNS');

// get the array from a namespace
$attributes = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('ns_15', array(), 'myNS');
// modify some value in the array
$attributes['Tel'] = '12345';
// remove some value from the array
unset($attributes['myID']);
// ... and save your changes back
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('ns_15', $attributes, 'myNS');
// remove the whole array from the namespase
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->remove('ns_15', null, 'myNS');
// remove the whole namespace
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->removeNamespace('myNS');
```

You can access a whole namespace as well:

```
// get all attributes from a namespace
$allAttributes = $this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->getAll('myNS');
// manipulate the whole namespace here...
// ...and save your changes back
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->add($allAttributes, 'myNS');
```

If you work on a same namespace and want to omit the namespace parameter:

```
$originalDefaultNs = $this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->getDefaultNamespace();
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->setDefaultNamespace('myNS', false);
// ...
$attributes = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('ns_15', array());
// ...
// don't forget to set back the original ns
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->setDefaultNamespace($originalDefaultNS, false);
```

I know it's really verbose, but I think there is no other way to do it in symfony. You can take a loot at the `sfNamespacedParameterHolder` class to see how these functions work.

Comment: All the get are working, but set dont work! I made an Edit! Thx.