# Symfony 1.4 Session vs $_SESSION Issues

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a strange behavior when i'm working on my development Installation( **Ubuntu 12.04 Firefox** ). I store values into my Session like this in a Component Class(..Components.class.php) : `$this->getUser()->setAttribute("ns1", myarray(), "globalNameSpace");`

When this Controller is called i see into Debug Modus that User Session is set, but Globals Session($_SESSION) is not set, then i can't accessed the Session for example with `$sf_user->getAttribute(...)` . I should reload the whole Page to see Globals Session($_SESSION) changes happened and then `$sf_user->getAttribute(...)` work.
 I should mention that i used under linux(ubuntu) the last Firefox and Chrome... i used the both into anonymus Tab too... but the problems still occured.

Is this a Settings Problems with factories.yml or just a symfony Bug?

**Edit:** The Controller is called through an ajax... maybe is this a problem too...

**Edit2:** I cannot Set User Session. In my factories.yml i have no session set. So into Dev i'm always cant set a session value! I think all my session is protected.

Comment: It's not a bug. Symfony stores user attributes in a `sfNamespacedParameterHolder` object. This object is not in sync with `$_SESSION` global variable every time. When a request comes in `$_SESSION` data is loaded into the attribute holder during user initialization and attributes saved to the `$_SESSION` at the end of request during shutdown. So I think you should use the user object to manipulate the session.

Comment: I use the user object but i can't write into sessions!